# Center a div in another div when parent div height is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center a div horizontally and vertically inside another div. My problem is that on window resize the width and height of parent div changes. For that, I have problems to center the div in the center of the parent div. 
Here is a case where I the width and height of the parent div is defined:

```
<div id="parent" style="">  
  <div id="child">Foo foo</div>
</div>
```

And the ccs:

```
#child {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:red;
  width:50px; 
  height:50px
}
#parent{
  background-color:blue;
  width:400px; 
  height:400px;
}
```

I don't know why it's so difficult to achieve it?  [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/32z4j66o/#&togetherjs=lgJFdtmxQ0)

Comment: All ok just add   position:relative; to your parent div . [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/5osqyjge/1/ ]

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to achieve it :)

https://jsfiddle.net/e4xhrvcf/

```
.parent{
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color:red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle, the child div is not centred, what if I use `display:block` in parent div?

Comment: Didn't you want it vertically centered? https://gyazo.com/b9f943889699e9fb0cd4aee78c0d0631

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS-Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by setting `display: flex;` for the parent div, and setting `margin: auto` for the child div.
remove the `top`,`bottom`,`right`,`left` from the css.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, I think you just need to add relative position to the parent in order to get absolute in the child to work:

```
#parent{
 background-color:blue;
 width:400px; 
 height:400px;
 position : relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrdVbO

```
#parent{
  position: relative;
  background-color:blue;
  width:400px; 
  height:400px;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color:red;
  width:50px; 
  height:50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The parent needs to have a `position` definition for the child's `absolute` to work. Use top and left 50% to center the left top corner of the child and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to move it back up and left by half of its own height and width.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

HTML

```
<div id="grandParent">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    foo foo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}

#grandParent{
  display: table;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#parent{
 background-color:red;
 display:table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

#child {
 background-color:blue;
 display:table;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

Fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/7o764szj/2/
```